# Deleting a string from a file

Tags: c, string, file

I'm coding in C. I have the following file ui.txt

```
user1 | 127.0.1.1
user2 | 127.0.1.1
user3 | 127.0.1.1
```

If I have a string str that is "user2", I need to find the line in ui.txt that has str, and delete that line so that I get

```
user1 | 127.0.1.1
user3 | 127.0.1.1
```

I have opened the file like this:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("ui.txt","a+");
```

I have opened it with a+ because any time I have to enter new info, say another user and their IP address, I have it append to the end of the file.

How do I go about this? Does it entail the use of fgetc or fgets? I've been using fgets so far. Please give me the complete code.

P.S. str can also be "user2 | 127.0.1.1" if that helps in simplifying the logic.

Comment: @Ben Basically so far I'm scanning the file line by line using fgets, storing the line in a string, comparing it with str. If it's not a match, go to the next line. But how do I proceed from there? Suppose I find str on the second line of the file.. how do I remove that line?

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking the same thing as here: [Delete a Line from a file in C Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151713/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-c-language), and also here: [deleting a string from a particular position in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496192/deleting-a-string-from-a-particular-position-in-a-file)

You will have to load the file into memory, edit it there, and then write it back to the disk.

Comment: Okay.. but can you tell me what functions I should use to achieve this? The way I see it, I should scan the file till I find str, write whatever is before and after str into a temporary file, and then copy the content of that temporary file back into the original file. How do I go to a particular position in the file?

Comment: you go to a particular position use [fseek](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek).  To read a line into a file, use `fread` or `fgets`

Comment: Okay but how do I *get* a position? For example.. how do I get to the position of the first character of the line which matches str? Only after getting it can I pass it to fseek right?

Comment: I'm not here to do your work for you.  Have you tried buying a C book? Or searching Google for "C Tutorial"?

Comment: Well okay no need to get snippy :/ It's just that I've spent hours on this already. Guess I should spend a while longer.

Comment: @cegfault: _"You will have to load the file into memory, edit it there, and then write it back to the disk"_ - he only needs to load the part after the deleted line into memory and copy it back to the file in the new place and change the EOF.